# How to place StickyGroupListView inside SingleChildScrollView on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, grouped-list

I have a widget tree like this: <b/r>

```
SingleChildScrollView
   Column
      Container
      StickyGroupedListView
```

The problem is that data inside StickyGroupedListView is not display on screen, only blank white screen. If I remove SingleChildScrollView, the list is display perfectly.
How to make it work with SingleChildScrollView ?

Comment: Hi! Please add your dart code instead widget structure

Comment: Just found out the solution. Thanks by the way.